# Resizing only one part of the Java Swing components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

On my Java Swing application I have two components. On the left side is a navigation (JList) and on the right side is a JTable. I would like to leave the possibility to increase the size of the window, without increasing the size of both components.

The proportion of 50/50 is kept, through ought the whole sizing. I use GridLayout. Is this behavior rooted into the LayoutManager or is a property which has to be set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GridbagLayout` will allow you to achieve this.  However, have you also considered using a `JSplitPane` where the left-hand side contains your navigation panel and the right hand side contains the table?  You could configure it so that all additional space is allocated to the right hand side by calling `setResizeWeight(0.0)`.  However, you still retain the flexibility of allowing the user to manually resize the navigation area if required.  You also have the option to hide your navigation panel completely by calling `setOneTouchExpandable(true)` on the split pane.

Answer (score 2):

From what I know the GridLayout manager resizes all cells to the same size. Knowing this you might use it anyway just add the component you want to stay unchanged to a panel and then add this panel to a cell instead.

Or use a different layout manager mine favourite is TableLayout, where you can set which columns/rows should fill the empty space where the rest will stay in their preferred size.

Good luck, Boro

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: Don't us GridLayout. Instead use other layouts such Borderlayout or GridBagLayout or a combination of layouts.  For instance if you used BorderLayout, you could but the JTable BorderLayout.CENTER and the JList in one of the other positions.  Or if you use GridBagLayout, then by setting your GridBagConstraint weightx and weighty values correctly and the fill values (only you know what you currently desire), would allow selective enlargement of the components added to the container.